# Good guide to using Ajax in a Django project?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I'm working on a Django project that will need jQuery, [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI), and one or two more JavaScript libraries. What good tutorial or reference can be recommend on how to make JavaScript and Django talk with each other? (that is, handling XMLHTTPRequests, passing information from a Django model to a JavaScript function, etc.)

Comment: Funnily enough, I asked a similar (not identical) question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307992/best-way-to-integrate-django-with-an-ajax

Comment: ah, tres bien! A mod can delete this if they want.

Comment: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jul/31/django-tips-simple-ajax-example-part-1/ http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/aug/05/django-tips-simple-ajax-example-part-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Ajax in Django is just like any other web request that comes to your Django application. You need to route the request to your controller which has to provide some HTML to jQuery's Ajax handler, that is, `X function(data){}`.

For more understanding, see *[Ajax in Django with jQuery](http://webcloud.se/log/AJAX-in-Django-with-jQuery/)*.